# RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0 using Getx in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

I make blog app by using flutter.

The app have problem when user go to postDetail page from postList.

error code

> he following RangeError was thrown building GetX(controller: null, tag: null, has builder, dirty, state: GetXState#9ee3c(controller: Instance of 'PostDetailController')):
> RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0

> The relevant error-causing widget was:
> GetX GetX:file:///E:/heyholder/app/lib/view/post_detail.dart:179:20

postDetail.dart

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return SafeArea(
    child: Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
  body: Column(
    children: [
      appBarContainer(),
      Expanded(
        child: GetX<PostDetailController>(
          builder: (controller) {
            return Scrollbar(child: postContainer(context, controller));
          },
        ),
      )
    ],
  ),
));
}

Widget postContainer(context, controller) {
  String postTitle = controller.post[0].postTitle;
  String userName = controller.post[0].userName;
  int holdCount = controller.post[0].holdCount;
  String createdTime = "createdTime";
  String postContent = controller.post[0].postContent;
  int likeCount = controller.post[0].likeCount;
  int commentCount = controller.post[0].commentCount;

return Container(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0, horizontal: 20.0),
  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
      border:
          Border(bottom: BorderSide(width: 1.0, color: Color(0xffE5E5E5)))),
  child: Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
    children: [
      headLineContainer(),
      const SizedBox(
        height: 10.0,
      ),
      Text(
        postTitle,
        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleLarge,
      ),
      const SizedBox(
        height: 6.0,
      ),
      Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          WriterInfo(userName: userName, holdCount: holdCount),
          createdTimeContainer(context, createdTime)
        ],
      ),
      const SizedBox(
        height: 20.0,
      ),
      Text(
        postContent,
        style: const TextStyle(
            fontSize: 13.0,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
            color: Color(0xff1e1e1e)),
      ),
      const SizedBox(
        height: 20.0,
      ),
      Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          IconButton2(
              iconSize: 17.0,
              icon: SvgPicture.asset('assets/images/ic_thumbs2.svg'),
              onPressed: () {}),
          const SizedBox(
            width: 2,
          ),
          Text(
            '$likeCount',
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyMedium,
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            width: 10,
          ),
          CountContainer(
              asset: 'assets/images/ic_reply2.svg', count: commentCount)
        ],
      )
    ],
  ),
);
}
```

postDetailController.dart

```
class PostDetailController extends GetxController {
final int postNo = Get.arguments;
var post = <PostModel>[].obs;

@override
void onInit() {
  super.onInit();
  fetchData();
}

void fetchData() async {
  String ip = "";
  ip = ipAddress();

  final uri = Uri.parse('$ip/api/v1/post/$postNo/1');
  http.Response response = await http.get(uri);
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    var data = jsonDecode(response.body);
    PostModel postData = PostModel.fromJson(data["body"]);
    post.assign(postData);
  }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check post(state) is not empty and then get the first element of post. Because of the beginning of the page, it needs to waste some time to get data from the cloud. So you can display different widget-tree depending on data.